# Using JSON_CONTAINS in MySQL query gets not result

Tags: mysql, json

I want a query to return all the fields for all the entries in the table minto_regsix_session that include a value of 2 in the 'day' field. Following is a screenshot from phpMyAdmin of the table including the day field which contains a JSON array.

[image: This is the data in the MySQL table]

This is the mysql query I'm using:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `minto_regsix_session` 
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(`day`, '2') = 1
```

The query returns an empty result. I would expect it to return the data from lines 2, 4, and 5. 
Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `minto_regsix_session` 
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(`day`, '"2"');
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It's so obvious when I see it but it never occurred to me at the time. I tried double quotes and single quotes and no quotes but I'm new to JSON and it didn't occur to me that I need to include the double quotes inside the single quotes. Much appreciated.

Comment: @user3765165 As documentation claims both arguments must be "valid JSON document". `'2'` is NOT valid JSON...

Comment: how to search for multiple values here?

Comment: @CuriousDeveloper Depends on the task. It can be "at least one is present" or "none is absent".

Comment: @Akina I have similar table as above in question. I want to search the value in any array for example if input is 1,2 then all row which contain both 1 & 2 or any of them.

Comment: @CuriousDeveloper If the column value is `["1", "2"]` and the criteria is `["2", "3"]` then the answer must be "matched", is it? if so then use JSON_OVERLAPS() fucntion.

Comment: @Akina yes, thats the criteria and result. I already tried JSON_OVERLAPS and unfortunately, I am getting error that this function doesn't exist. I have mysql 5.7 and I guess this function exists in mysql 8.0

Comment: If i write multiple conditions to get the same result it will work with JSON_CONTAINS